# Destroy an activity when back button is pressed?

Tags: android

I have an app that allows user to select a txt file from a list and then goes off to the internet to get the contents of that file. All works well except when the user accidentally or deliberately presses the hardware back button to go and see the list again.

Now, when the user clicks a new item from the list (a new file that is), instead of loading a the new file, the app continues off from where it was suspended.I do not want that to happen. I know this is related to the life cycle of the activity.

How do I make sure that it loads the new file rather than continuing from where it left off ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you're loading the file in `onCreate()`. You should do that in `onResume()` instead.

[image: Android Application Lifecycle]

Do not force Activities to close (e.g. use `finish()`). First, [this does not guarantee the Activity will be closed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29), and second, this is better left to Android to decide.

Comment: The thing is, I want a whole new file to be fetched from the internet. This means stopping the `AsyncTask` doing the loading of the first file. Then, spawning a new one for the second file.
So, this will need to be done in `onPause` I guess, then start a new `AsyncTask` in `onStart`. That way my code will not be disturbed. :)

Comment: Then you should keep track of the `AsyncTask` fetching the old text file and cancel it.

Comment: Where to cancel previous `AsyncTask` depends on the logic. Maybe the user that navigates back to this `Activity` does not want a new file, just take a look at the previous file. You need to study the involved cases.

Comment: Ahhh yes !! That too !! How do I know if `AsyncTask` is running ? Apart from doing that manually, that is !! :)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29

Answer (score 1):

Another Method to kill an activity is by calling following method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `onBackPressed` method in the activity and call `finish()` to get the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to finish your activity in onBackPressed() method by calling **activity.finish()**;

Comment: `Activity#finish()` does not guarantee your Activity is closed. Read the documentation.

Comment: finish() is not destroying the activity

Answer (score 0):

To destroy activity on back press, use this code.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     //Destroys activity.
     finish();
}
```

Comment: //Destroys activity -> No, it does not.

Comment: try to use this.finish(); instead of finish();

Comment: Errr... `this.finish()` is exactly same as `finish()`. What I mean is `finish()` does not destroy the activity. Read the documentation.

Comment: Oaky Try this.
I am also using it. It works for me.

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

Comment: You don't seem to understand what I mean. If you read the documentation: finish() does not guarantee your Activity will be destroyed. It only informs Android that this Activity is no longer needed. Android will destroy (which is not the same as close) **when it likes**, not when you call finish().

Comment: Okay, does it serve your purpose? Can I look at your code segment where you are using it?

Comment: You can easily see that I'm not the one asking this question. I'm **correcting** your answer. And you do not need to call finish() to solve the question being asked here. In fact, you (almost) never need to call finish(), ever. If you think calling finish() solves a problem, then 99% you don't understand how Android works.